# Como esconder blocos para uma rota ao ir para um sub-rota

Tags: javascript, emberjs

Estou usando Ember 2 e as coisas são complicadas para quem não tem experiencia Ember. Eu tenho as seguinte rotas

`consultas\`

`consultas\reserva`

E no meu router.js está assim

```
this.route('consultas', function() {
    this.route('reservas');
}
```

O template de consultas tem algumas informações que quero esconder quando vou para o template de reservas. 
Como posso fazer isso em Ember 2.0 ou como faço para saber qual rota estou ao chamar o meu helper para fazer isso?

Fiz essa mesma pergunta no SOEN. Caso queiram acompanhar as [respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393426/how-hide-a-block-for-a-route-in-ember-when-go-to-a-sub-route/33393702#33393702).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia ter a seguinte estrutura de templates:

> consultas.hbs
>   consultas/index.hbs
>   consultas/reservas.hbs

No *consultas.hbs* haveria um `{{outlet}}`.
Quando você estivesse na rota consultas, o Ember renderizaria o *consultas/index.hbs* nesse `{{outlet}}`.
Quando você estivesse na rota consultas/reservas, o Ember renderizaria o *consultas/reservas.hbs* no `{{outlet}}`.

Dessa maneira, tudo que estivesse no *index.hbs* seria mostrado na rota pai, mas não na sub-rota. Bastaria colocar o que você quer esconder no *index.hbs*.

Contudo, isso só funcionaria bem para blocos contíguos de código. Se as informações que você quer esconder estiverem muito espalhadas no template, talvez seja melhor usar uma variável na rota consultas para definir quando elas devem ser mostradas, e usar o willTransition para detectar quando estiver entrando na rota filha.